# How to convert SOAP response with xsi values to json in WSO2esb

Tags: json, soap, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 4.8.1 version for SOAP to rest conversion with as API. I have a soap request with xsi values. After I generate the proper soap request with script mediator and um getting an expected response. But I have an issue with response. Because I need t convert the soap response into json. When I tried with following out sequence um not getting the proper json response with axis2. How can I convert this soap response into json properly?

This it the soap response.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:easyDownloadResponse xmlns:ns1="http://usermanage.ivas.huawei.com" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<easyDownloadReturn href="#id0"/>
</ns1:easyDownloadResponse>
<multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://response.usermanage.ivas.huawei.com" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:EasyDownloadResp">
<eventClassName xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
<failedResources xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"/>
<operationID xsi:type="xsd:long">0</operationID>
<resultCode xsi:type="xsd:int">0</resultCode>
<resultInfo xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
<returnCode xsi:type="xsd:string">000000</returnCode>
<toneTransactionID xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"/>
<transactionID xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
</multiRef>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response which i'm getting

```
{"easyDownloadResponse":{"@encodingStyle":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/","easyDownloadReturn":{"@href":"#id0"}}}
```

This is my out sequence

```
<outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <send></send>
</outSequence>
```

All your answers are highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for the issue. In the normal case we use

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
```

But this axis2 property cannot convert the complex soap response into json such as with xsi.
For that need to use the following axis2 property. Then it converts the entire soap response into Json as we expected.

```
 <property name="messageType" value="application/json/badgerfish" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
```

This is my full outsequence.

```
<outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json/badgerfish" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <send></send>
</outSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [payload mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator) to get exact json format [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator). But still you may have to uncomment the following lines in

> $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

```
<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamFormatter"/-->

<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder"/-->
```

By default, JSON messages are converted to XML when they are received by the PayloadFactor mediator. However, if you enable the JSON stream formatter and builder, incoming JSON messages are left in JSON format.

And also you can use script mediator again (In outsequence) to modify your json response. Refer [this sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+441%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+JavaScript)

Comment: In my case this should be implemented with Script mediator. Cannot use payload factory, coz need to check optional parameters. WIth the use of "<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>" simple we can convert xml response to json. But now um getting "XSI" also with my response and cannot convert that xml response to json properly

Comment: As property mediator just use to conver XML format in to JSON, it will react in different way with naming conventions. So you can use script mediator and define the json fromat through scripting language like js. you can see sample through doc: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support

Comment: can you please provide a sample code for out sequence.