# WSO2 - How to convert this XML to Json using script mediator?

Tags: json, xml, api, wso2, esb

Im using WSO2 ESB and DDS to make an API to read data from database and finally I got this respone. How to convert this XML to Json using script mediator? Give me an example please.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Body>
    <employeeCollection xmlns="http://employee.us.wso2.com">
        <employee>
            <EmployeeID>17</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
            <LastName>123</LastName>
            <Team>ok</Team>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <EmployeeID>18</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
            <LastName>123</LastName>
            <Team>ok</Team>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <EmployeeID>19</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
            <LastName>123</LastName>
            <Team>ok</Team>
        </employee>

    </employeeCollection>
</soapenv:Body>
```

And this is the configuration

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/team">
  <inSequence>
     <sequence key="conf:/SendSelectWithTeam"/>
     <call>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="https://192.168.2.165:9453/services/EmployeesDataService/" format="soap12"/>
        </endpoint>
     </call>

     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
```

Additional question: How to get the value of the each of "EmployeeID" using script mediator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert this directly to json, you don't need to do it manually using script mediator.

You can update the out sequence of your ESB proxy (or API) like this and it will convert the response xml to json.

```
<outSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <send/>
</outSequence>
```

See [WSO2 Docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-ConvertingapayloadbetweenXMLandJSON) for more details.

Edit:

In your case, if you use `<respond>` mediator, it will bypass out sequence, and my suggestion won't work. You have 2 options to get it working.

1) Use Send mediator instead of `call` and `respond` mediators.

or

2) Use `loopback` mediator instead of `respond` mediator.

Comment: thanks, its work. but i want to modify the response. if use script, how to get the value of first "EmployeeID" ?

Comment: Try this. `<script language="js">var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON(); var emp = payload.employee.EmployeeID; </script>`

Comment: the return of getPayloadJSON is null

Comment: Solved. i use payload mediator first to convert the response to JSON then use `<script language="js">var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON(); var emp = payload.employee.EmployeeID; </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link

[How to convert SOAP response with xsi values to json in WSO2esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432867/how-to-convert-soap-response-with-xsi-values-to-json-in-wso2esb)

Please change the proxy  outSequence settings in config file like below:

```
  <outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json/badgerfish" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <send></send>
</outSequence>
```