# WSO2 ESB - XML to JSON using Script mediator

Tags: javascript, json, xml, wso2

Im using WSO2 ESB and DDS to make an API and get finally get this response. How to process this response from XML to JSON with some editing using script mediator?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body>
<employeeCollection xmlns="http://employee.us.wso2.com">
    <employee>
        <EmployeeID>17</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
        <LastName>123</LastName>
        <Team>ok</Team>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <EmployeeID>18</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
        <LastName>123</LastName>
        <Team>ok</Team>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <EmployeeID>19</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>jak</FirstName>
        <LastName>123</LastName>
        <Team>ok</Team>
    </employee>
</employeeCollection>
```

I want the result like this

`{  "status": "success",
    "employee": [
      {
        "EmployeeID": 17,
        "FirstName": "jak",
        "LastName": 123,
        "Team": "ok"
      },
      {
        "EmployeeID": 18,
        "FirstName": "jak",
        "LastName": 123,
        "Team": "ok"
      },
      {
        "EmployeeID": 19,
        "FirstName": "jak",
        "LastName": 123,
        "Team": "ok"
      }]
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 - How to convert this XML to Json using script mediator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034781/wso2-how-to-convert-this-xml-to-json-using-script-mediator)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can refer one of the following,

http://abeykoon.blogspot.com/2015/03/wso2-esb-convert-xml-to-json.html
http://tryitnw.blogspot.com/2014/11/wso2-esb-how-to-convert-xml-to-json.html
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+441%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+JavaScript
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator

Comment: Thanks! i use both payload mediator and script mediator and its work